# Cannot run android application

Tags: java, android-studio, android-emulator

I'm trying to run my Android application in Android Studio but I had this error:

```
  emulator: WARNING: Requested RAM size of 1536MB is too large for your environment, and is reduced to 864MB.
   emulator: device fd:576
   HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode
   Cannot set up guest memory 'pc.ram': Invalid argument
   Error accepting connection, aborting
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

At the moment of run , the computer simply cannot provide the requested amount of RAM ( you have opened applications that consume a large amount i.e Firefox ). Lower the amount needed. If you are running with HAX , with 768MB (i used with 512) will work just great.

Answer (score 1):

Basically this issues arrived due to the fact that PC is not able to allocate that much RAM to the new Emulator.

It can be solved by this --

In Android Studio, version 1.2.1.1:

Go to "Tools -> Android -> AVD Manager -> Chose your device -> Edit -> Advanced Settings -> Change the RAM parameter to 512 Mb.

Save it, and run the App in the Emulator. It should run now.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you. Decreasing RAM in Virtual Device settings is a good idea!